# How to show default content if function returns nothing

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the code below to check for the title of a book in the URL parameters and if it exists, show that book on the page. How can I amend this so that if no content is shown, default content displays? Something like "no products selected"?

```
function makeDiv(title, url) {
  contentDiv = `
  ${title} <br>
  ${url}
  `;
  return contentDiv;
}

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  return url ?? location.href.split(`?${name}=`)[1];
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  const queryParams = getParameterByName("q");

  const params = queryParams
  .split("+")
  .map((item) => decodeURI(item).toLowerCase());

  const mainDiv = document.querySelector("#mainDiv");

  data.forEach((element) => {
    if (params.includes(element.title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, ""))) {
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = makeDiv(
        element.title,
        element.url,
        );
      mainDiv.appendChild(div);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your `makeDiv()` function to

```
function makeDiv(title, url) { 
  return title.trim()>"" ? `${title}<br>${url}` : "No title selected.";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the `mainDiv` has no children after the `data.forEach` execution, then append with 'no products' text in the `mainDiv`.
You can make use of `Node.hasChildNodes()`

```
if(!mainDiv.hasChildNodes())
  mainDiv.innerText = "no products";
```

Comment: Updated the answer. It should be added at the end of the document ready scope.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it still doesn't work. When I check the console im getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` for the line in the code that I pasted with `.split("+")`. This error only happens when there are no queries for a product in the url.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to add another function that is proofing if the input field is empty, and if the case is true, to display your default message, otherwise it should run your "search" function.